# Expose MongoDB from docker container

Tags: docker, mongodb

I am trying to expose my mongodb that is running in a docker container to be accessible from the outside.

I found out that it should be able with docker compose or the mongod.conf file to set the host binding there but as I use the offical mongodb docker image I did not do a compose and I can't find the conf file as well.

here is what I did and what I've tried so far:

1. created a network

> docker network create my-mongo-cluster

2. ran 3 mongo db instances

> docker run --name mongo-node1 -d --net my-mongo-cluster mongo --replSet "rs0"
>   docker run --name mongo-node2 -d --net my-mongo-cluster mongo --replSet "rs0"
>   docker run --name mongo-node3 -d --net my-mongo-cluster mongo --replSet "rs0"

3. executed the first

   > docker exec -it mongo-node1 mongo
4. set up the config for the replica set

> config = {
>             "_id" : "rs0",
>             "members" : [
>                 {
>                     "_id" : 0,
>                     "host" : "mongo-node1:27017"
>                 },
>                 {
>                     "_id" : 1,
>                     "host" : "mongo-node2:27017"
>                 },
>                 {
>                     "_id" : 2,
>                     "host" : "mongo-node3:27017"
>                 }
>             ]
>         }
>
> rs.initiate(config)
>      rs.initialize

6. created an admin user

   use admin    db.createUser(
    {
      user: "admin",
      pwd: "admin", 
      roles: [ { role: "userAdminAnyDatabase", db: "admin" }, >"readWriteAnyDatabase" ]
    }    )

I tried running the containers with the following statements:

```
--expose=27017
--auth

--entrypoint 'mongod --bind_ip_all'
```

-> leads to an error.

it is running within AWS and the inbound rule for 27017 is set up correctly.

Answer is always:

```
couldn't connect to server ec2-52-59-191-1.eu-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com:27017, connection attempt failed: SocketException: Error connecting to ec2-52-59-191-1.eu-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com:27017 (52.59.191.1:27017) :: caused by :: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. :
```